# Laravel 5 customizing authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, customization

In Laravel 5 how can you customize the default authentication which comes out of the box? For example I have multiple types of users to authenticate against. Each type of user is defined by a role i.e Jobseeker, Recruiter etc. Each type of user will have a different type of registration form to capture some of the profile details as well. So I have the following tables:

```
users
roles
role_user
jobseeker_profile
recruiter_profile
```

The default authcontroller and passwordcontroller in Laravel 5 uses traits for all the authentication methods. How would you go about customizing it - do you guys edit the existing trait files? So for example the getRegister method returns the register view but I would want it to check the route before deciding which view to show.

```
// default method
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

// custom method
public function getRegister()
{
  if (Request::is('jobseeker/register'))
  {
    return view('auth.jobseeker_register');
  }
  elseif (Request::is('recruiter/register'))
  {
    return view('auth.recruiter_register');
  }

}
```

Similarly the default postLogin method is as follows:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

But I would want the method to also check the user roles as follows:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'recruiter')
        {
           return redirect()->to('/recruiter/dashboard');
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->role->name == 'jobseeker')
        {
           return redirect()->to('jobseeker/dashboard');
        }

    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

So my question is how do you go about customizing the existing authentication? Do you guys create a new controller perhaps CustomAuthController, CustomPasswordController and copy all the traits from the default auth controllers into these custom controllers and edit them as appropriate? I'm unable to find any Laravel 5 tutorials on how to acheive this - they all simply talk about the default out of the box authentication. If anyone has done something similar before I would love to hear about how you went about it and which files were edited to wire this custom auth up.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Override the methods in the existing auth controller.
2. Just don’t implement the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait at all, and implement authentication logic entirely yourself.

With regards to redirect, I’d listen on the `auth.login` event, check your user’s type there, and then redirect to the specific dashboard there and then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. With regards to the redirect how do you listen on the auth.login event - sorry but I'm new to laravel, some example code would be useful. Also if I implement the authentication logic myself, would I also have to tweak the `passwordController`, the `Authenticate` and `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware aswell?